# Evaluating a commutator involving exponentials?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, noncommutative-algebra

I am interested in evaluating the commutator $[e^V,e^W]$ where we know that $[V,W]=c$, and $V$ and $W$ are vector fields.

I know that $e^V= 1 + V + \frac{V^2}{2}+\frac{V^3}{6}+\dots$, so I can see that, say, $[V, e^W]=[V,1 + W + \frac{W^2}{2}+\frac{W^3}{6}+\dots]=[V,1]+[V,W]+\frac{1}{2}[V,W^2]+\dots$

or something along those lines (which is apprently supposed to simplify to $ce^W$?), but trying to expand $[e^V, e^W]$ seems impossible to do reasonably, yet the answer is supposed to be fairly simple, at least when put to a low order. Is there any tricks or obvious thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the commutator trivializes to a constant,  $[V,W]=c$, 
the [CBH expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) collapses to the trivial form,
$$
e^V e^W= e^{V+W+ c/2},
$$
that is the expansion *terminates after the leading term*.

You then have 
$$[e^V,e^W]= e^{V+W+ c/2} - e^{V+W- c/2}=  e^{V+W} ~2\sinh (c/2).  $$

A word of warning: taking Lie algebra [commutators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator) of *group elements*, instead of group commutators, is highly peculiar, and you must double-check your application.

Comment: I guess $[B,C]=0$ so CBH=BCH? (Sorry, could not resist.)

Comment: @Torsten No doubt... On a "serious" note (haha..) usage is mixed, but the majority has opted for alphabetical, as opposed to historical ordering. If you read the papers, B should hardly be there, and Poincare, should, instead.